# MySQL: Dynamically export CSV file with headers on top

Tags: mysql, dynamic, header, export-to-csv

I want to dynamically export CSV files with headers from mySQL. I tried the answer of shadow0359: *[MySQL: Dynamically export CSV file with headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475429/mysql-dynamically-export-csv-file-with-headers)*,  but his solution, i believe exports the header on the bottom of the records and not on the top. Does anyone knows how to dynamically export CSV files from mySQL with headers on top?

My Code (Scripts to create):

**Stored Procedure**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `p_test`(in_Accountid 
varchar(30))
BEGIN

SET @default_group_concat_max_len = (SELECT @@group_concat_max_len);
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET @FilePath:='C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/';
SET @FileName:=CONCAT(in_AccountID,'_',DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m- 
%d'),'.xls');
SET @FullFilePath:=CONCAT(@FilePath,@FileName);
SET @TableName:='temp_transactionslines';
SET @TableSchema:='melhor_metade_2016';

SET @SQL = ( select CONCAT('SELECT  
                        TransactionID
                        ,RecordID
                        ,AccountID
                        ,AccountDescription
                        ,SourceDocumentID
                        ,SystemEntryDate
                        ,Description
                        ,DebitAmount
                        ,CreditAmount
                        ,Period
                        ,TransactionDate
                        ,CustomerTaxID
                        ,CustomerID 
                        INTO OUTFILE \''
                        , @FullFilePath, '\'
                        FROM (SELECT '
                            ,group_concat(CONCAT("'", COLUMN_NAME,"'"))
                            ,' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM 
temp_transactionslines  order by TransactionID ASC) as tmp')

        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema
        order BY ORDINAL_POSITION );

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @default_group_concat_max_len;

PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_transactionslines` (
`TransactionID` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`RecordID` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`AccountID` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`AccountDescription` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`SourceDocumentID` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
`SystemEntryDate` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
`Description` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`DebitAmount` float(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`CreditAmount` float(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`Period` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`TransactionDate` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
`CustomerTaxID` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`CustomerID` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`SupplierID` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 KEY `i_accountID` (`AccountID`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Data**

```
INSERT INTO `melhor_metade_2016`.`temp_transactionslines`
(`TransactionID`,
`RecordID`,
`AccountID`,
`AccountDescription`,
`SourceDocumentID`,
`SystemEntryDate`,
`Description`,
`DebitAmount`,
`CreditAmount`,
`Period`,
`TransactionDate`,
`CustomerTaxID`,
`CustomerID`,
`SupplierID`)
VALUES
('a','b',3,4,5,2, 1, 1,null,3,1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: You "believe"? Did you try it?

Comment: Absolutely, yes I tried it and the headers always go to last line! Try it also if you do not believe me!

Comment: I've already tried the second (simplified) part - and it worked fine. You sould post your sample data and the code that didn't work for you. However - I would replace `UNION` with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: The simplified part is not dynamic, its a static version. I also changed the union to union all and has no impact, the headers go to bottom.

Comment: I will post my code and sample data but it differs not much from shadow0359, the only difference its that I removed the where condition on the query to simplify.

Comment: You have an `ORDER BY` after  `UNION`. Replace `UNION ALL SELECT * FROM 
temp_transactionslines  order by TransactionID ASC` by `UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM 
temp_transactionslines  order by TransactionID ASC)`.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

You generate the following query:

```
SELECT 'TransactionID'
      ,'RecordID'
      ,'AccountID'
      -- more column names
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM temp_transactionslines
order by TransactionID ASC
```

The ORDER BY clause applies to to the full UNION set. If you only want to sort the second query result, you should wrap the query into parentheses:

```
SELECT 'TransactionID'
      ,'RecordID'
      ,'AccountID'
      -- more column names
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM temp_transactionslines  order by TransactionID ASC)
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fSXBH527fxg9hXy1JYGHyQ/0